# JScript hide logo when clicking menu bar

Tags: javascript

I want to hide the previous logo and menu bar but when I click the menu bar. But the result is not expect.

[image]

HTML:

```
<div class="header">
     <img src="common/img/logo.png" class="logo">
     <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
     <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn" onclick="myChk()">
         <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
     </label>
     <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
         <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
     </label>
```

Script:

```
function myChk(){

    var image = document.getElementById("show-menu-btn");

    if(image.src.match("show-menu-btn")){
        image.src = "none";
    }else{
        image.src = "common/img/logo.png";
    }
}
```

Comment: There is no 'Id' attribute set on img. Instead of changing src, you can do image.style.diplay = 'none' for hiding and image.style.diplay = 'inline-block' for showing.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of changing src, you can do image.style.diplay = 'none' for hiding and image.style.diplay = 'inline-block' for showing.

HTML

```
<div class="header">
     <img src="common/img/logo.png" class="logo" id="logo">
     <input type="checkbox" id="chk">
     <label for="chk" class="show-menu-btn" onclick="myChk()">
         <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
     </label>
     <label for="chk" class="hide-menu-btn">
         <i class="fas fa-times"></i>
     </label>
</div>
```

JS:

```
function myChk(){

    var image = document.getElementById("logo");

    if(image.style.display === 'none'){
        image.style.display = "inline-block";
    }else{
        image.style.display = "none";
    }
}
```

Comment: Updated the answer, can you check now.